# Нужно ли второе тире после "воздуха"?

Tags: пунктуация

> Однако сесть можно и в колоннаде – на воздухе или расположиться в
>   холле.

Comment: А где находится холл? В колоннаде? Или же нет? Правильно расставить знаки препинания можно, лишь зная ответы на эти вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однако сесть можно и в колоннаде – **на воздухе** – или расположиться в холле.

Вставная уточняющая конструкция, выделяется двумя паузами и двумя тире.

Второе тире сохраняется  перед одиночным союзом **при отсутствии запятой**.

У Розенталя: Достали глубиномер — гирьку на длинной бечёвке — и промерили глубину.

Answer (score 1):

В тире, думаю, необходимости нет, оно было бы нужно, если бы пояснение было распространённым.

Возможно так, как есть.

Возможно с запятыми:

*Однако сесть можно и в колоннаде, на воздухе, или расположиться в холле.*

Можно и совсем без знаков препинания:

*Однако сесть можно и в колоннаде  на воздухе или расположиться в холле.*

Answer (score 1):

По моему, "на воздухе" надо выделять с двух сторон (запятыми, тире, скобками) или вовсе не выделять. При одном тире создается впечатение, что все, что за ним, — пояснение.